# How to sort by subarray id in Mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

I am wondering how do I sort a subarray in Mongodb.

I have the following

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("_id"=>new MongoId($this->data['cid'])));
            $cursor->sort(array("replied"=>array("replyid"=>1)));
                if ($cursor->count() > 0)
                {
                    $test = array();
                    // iterate through the results
                    while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                    $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
                    }
                    return $test;
                }
```

however I have tried `$cursor->sort(array("replied"=>array("replyid"=>0)));` and `$cursor->sort(array("replied"=>array("replyid"=>1)));` with no success

I am wondering if I need to do it on the foreach statement

```
<?php
            if($customersupport[0]['replies'] != NULL)
            {
            foreach($customersupport[0]['replies'] as $customer_reply)
            {
            ?>
            <div style="border-bottom:thin solid #666;">
                <span style="color:#666;float:left; width:40%;">
                <?php if($customer_reply['whoreplied'] == "user"){
                    $usertwo = $fetch->namesearch($customer_reply['uid']);
                }else{
                    $usertwo = $fetch->adminnamesearch($customer_reply['uid']);
                }
                    print $usertwo[0]['personalinfo']['firstname']." ".$usertwo[0]['personalinfo']['lastname'];
                ?></span><span style="float:right; width:40%; text-align:right;font-size:12px;"><?=$customer_reply['replydate'];?></span>
                <br>
                <?=$customer_reply['msg'];?>
            </div>
            <?php 
            }
            }
            ?>
```

Here is a sample of our mongodb

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5XXXXXXXX000000"),
   "issue": "test",
   "replies": {
     "0": {
       "replyid"▼: ObjectId("5014cXXXXXXXXXX0000"),
       "replydate": "29\/07\/2012CDT00: 18: 50",
       "whoreplied": "user",
       "uid": ObjectId("4fXXXXXXXXXXXXX00"),
       "msg": "test" 
    } 
  },
   "status": "Issued",
   "subject": "test",
   "uid": ObjectId("4XXXXXXXX000000") 
}
```

Comment: What is your actual document structure; are you trying to sort by `replied.reply_id` ?  Also, what does "no success" mean .. was there a specific error, no result, ... ?

Comment: I think you are trying to sort the subdocument itself. WHat MongoDB version is this. I am not sure even the 2.2 release works to sort subdocuments yet without the use of the aggregation framework.

Comment: could I use usort or something

Comment: @RussellHarrower: yes, given your document structure [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) looks like the most straightforward option.  If you are appending to the document array with [$push](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating/#Updating-%24push) there shouldn't be a need to sort, though?

Comment: yes I am using $push but not sure why its not working @Stennie could you give a quick sample of a usort() I have not used it before.

Comment: @Stennie i ended up using array_reverse() which worked just as well. thx